# Does this sentence make sense? ( I go to school hungry.)

Tags: grammar

I want to know if this sentence makes sense.

> I go to school hungry.

If this sentence makes sense, what is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: This question is too broad.  It is grammatical, perfectly idiomatic English.  Do you not understand it? If so, what in particular gives you trouble?

Comment: It means that the person speaking has not eaten before going to school. Depending on context there is an implication that they (or their parents) can't afford a healthy breakfast. (Some schools and charities provide free breakfast before school specifically to help with this problem.)

Comment: What if it's night school?

Comment: @TRomano - I've edited my previous comment, but to respond to your question directly: certainly there is no reason why this expression couldn't be used by anyone (students of all ages, teachers, admin staff) going to school at any time of the day or night, but most commonly - here in Australia, anyway - "going to school hungry" refers to primary or secondary students whose home/family situation prevents them from having breakfast before school. It isn't normally used for kids who voluntarily skipped breakfast, even if they did in fact end up hungry on a particular day.

Comment: Of course, but my point is that you're explaining a *possible* (even likely) cultural context in which the sentence could be spoken, but the OP seems to be having some trouble with the grammar.

Comment: You could also be hungry for knowledge. It is a school after all. Usually it's thirsty, but that could still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the modifiers at the end of these sentences. They all apply to the subject of the verb. At the end of the clause, they occupy a position of prominence. There is a syntactic pause before the modifier-phrase (often reflected in writing with a comma) and the modifier receives an intonation  which identifies it as applying not to a noun that immediately precedes it (e.g. ocean, woods) but to the subject of the verb.

> He went to the job interview drunk.
>
> He stared at her speechless.
>
> He swims in the ocean naked.
>
> He wandered the woods dizzy.
>
> The dog ran indoors dripping wet.

Answer (score 0):

It means when the subject (I) goes to school, he or she is hungry.

You can also say

I go hungry all day.

Which means the speaker *is* hungry all day. This can be  because there is no food or because the person does not eat.